# Catching all exceptions in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, python-3.x, catch-all

In Python, what's the best way to catch "all" exceptions?

```
except: # do stuff with sys.exc_info()[1]

except BaseException as exc:

except Exception as exc:
```

The catch may be executing in a thread.

My aim is to log any exception that might be thrown by normal code without masking any special Python exceptions, such as those that indicate process termination etc.

Getting a handle to the exception (such as by the clauses above that contain `exc`) is also desirable.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you need to catch all exceptions and do the same stuff for all, I'll suggest you this :

```
try:
   #stuff
except:
   # do some stuff
```

If you don't want to mask "special" python exceptions, use the Exception base class

```
try:
   #stuff
except Exception:
   # do some stuff
```

for some exceptions related management, catch them explicitly :

```
try:
   #stuff
except FirstExceptionBaseClassYouWantToCatch as exc:
   # do some stuff
except SecondExceptionBaseClassYouWantToCatch as exc:
   # do some other stuff based
except (ThirdExceptionBaseClassYouWantToCatch, FourthExceptionBaseClassYouWantToCatch) as exc:
   # do some other stuff based
```

The [exception hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) from the python docs should be a usefull reading.

Comment: How can I then get the caught exception instance if the except class is not defined?

Comment: @Mvorisek use `except Exception as exc`, Eception is the base class of all exceptions, so it will catch everything.

Comment: Be careful in using first one, it will catch literally everything, including syntax errors!
Generally it is considered bad practice to use except without specifying the type of exception.

Answer (score 71):

- `except Exception:` vs `except BaseException:`:

  The difference between catching `Exception` and `BaseException` is that according to the [exception hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) exception like SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt and GeneratorExit will not be caught when using `except Exception` because they inherit directly from `BaseException`.
- `except:` vs `except BaseException:`:

  The difference between this two is mainly in python 2 (AFAIK), and it's only when using an old style class as an Exception to be raised, in this case only expression-less except clause will be able to catch the exception eg.

  ```
  class NewStyleException(Exception): pass

  try:
     raise NewStyleException
  except BaseException:
     print "Caught"

  class OldStyleException: pass

  try:
     raise OldStyleException
  except BaseException:
     print "BaseException caught when raising OldStyleException"
  except:
     print "Caught"
  ```

Comment: I made `NewStyleException` inherit from `Exception`, as is officially recommended (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions).

Answer (score -1):

In order to avoid masking basic exceptions, you need to "re-raise" any exceptions which aren't the ones which you explicitly want to handle, e.g. (adapted from [8. Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)):

```
import sys
```

try:
    # do something that could throw an exception:
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    # maybe log the exception (e.g. in debug mode)
    # re-raise the exception:
    raise

Comment: The final `except: raise` does not do anything: it can be skipped altogether; non-IOError and non-ValueError exceptions are simply not caught and are automatically raised by the interpreter.

Comment: @EOL You're right. I have edited my answer to indicate why the final except: might be useful.